# Upload a Django website from local machine to server

Tags: python, django, web-hosting

I have a web application made using Django on my local machine. I want to upload it to a server hosted by Network Solutions. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

This comment from an admin is from years back, but if it's the same situation, you can't use Django on that host. http://forums.networksolutions.com/script-help-perl-php-asp-net-f50-how-to-deploy-a-django-web-application-t8019.html

> Django has to be installed via command line or by placing it in the site-packages folder of the python installation. Since we're in a shared environment these options aren't available so, I apologize, Django won't be a usable option for you. - rshinsec

Consider https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoFriendlyWebHosts

Comment: For this and several other reasons, Network Solutions is a bad host.

Comment: The first link has a lot of info, I don't think I can explain all that here. I can only pretty much quote the second one.